# excel conditional formatting formula issues

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have the following formula

```
=AND(A1="USA",I6=0)
```

it applies to `=$I$6:$I$100` 
 I want the compare to A1 remain intact and I6 through I100 should always compare to A1.

As it stands currently the A1 is being used for comparison on I6, and A2 not A1 is being used to do the conditional formatting to I7.

Can someone help me with this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try "Format Painter" with `I6` selected, and drag the mouse from `I7` to `I100`.  If your formatting has references in it, you may have to make them non-absolute if necessary.

Comment: Thanks i tried format painter, in that case the first reference shifts to A2, i want it to stay at A1.

Comment: Glad to see it's solved.  You should change the title of the question - it's not really an issue with conditional formatting, but cell references instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one did it

=AND($A$1="USA",$I6="") range =$I$6:$I$10000

Answer (score 0):

Have you applied the format to the column of the cell?

Try using the format paste tool to copy the format to the range range.

Have you checked the condition is true for the other cells?

Comment: I have applied formatting to the cell. Asi mentioned i want the first compare to always stay at A1 and I6 through I100 should be compared.